# AngularJS custom directive doesn't load

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-directive

I'm using angular 1.4.x.

I'm making a custom directive that checks weather a field is unique on the server (the field is called "jmbg"). I have the following code:

```
(function() {
angular
    .module('app')
    .directive('uniqueJmbg', uniqueJmbg);

uniqueJmbg.$inject = ['$q', '$http'];
function uniqueJmbg($q, $http) {
    restrict: 'A',
    require: 'ngModel',
    link: function(scope, elem, attrs, ngModelCtrl) {
        ngModelCtrl.$asyncValidators.uniqueJmbg = function(modelValue, viewValue) {
            var value = modelValue || viewValue;

            return $http.get('/server/users/' + value)
                .then(function resolved() {
                    return $q.reject('exists');
                }, function rejected() {
                    return true;
             });
        };
    }
}
})();
```

I am using the directive in HTML in the following way:

```
<input class="form-control" type="text" id="jmbg" name="jmbg" ng-model="rad.radnik.jmbg" ng-model-options="{ updateOn: 'default blur', debounce: {'default':400, 'blur':0 } }" unique-jmbg/>
```

In case it matters, I'm using my controllers with the controllerAs syntax.
Now, what happens is that the file containing my uniqueJmbg definition never loads (I can't see it in the browser debugger). If I move my code to a component which does load the app stops working (and there are no errors in the console), so there is no way for me to debug this.

Any idea what might be so wrong I can't even access the code in the browser?

Comment: This may sound a bit silly, but are you loading the directive.js file in your index.html file?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add dependencies to the module

```
angular
    .module('app', [])
    .directive(...
```

And you need to return an object from the module, so the correction would be:

```
function uniqueJmbg($q, $http) {
    return {
        restrict: 'A',
        require: 'ngModel',
        link: function(scope, elem, attrs, ngModelCtrl) {
            ...
        }
    };
}
```

Comment: I think your first correction is wrong—from the wording, it sounds like the OP defines the `app` module elsewhere, in which case the one-argument call to `module` is correct. The second part of your answer is accurate, though.

Comment: It is defined elsewhere, that's why you need dependencies for the module (if there are any, it can stay as an empty array). So you can inject them there as `angular.module('app.whatever.module', ['app.whatever.dependency']).directive()`

Comment: No no, the OP is using the single-argument version of `module` to act as a getter. In that case the two-argument version is *wrong* because it will attempt to redefine a new module with the same name.

Comment: I can see what you're saying, I agree, but I have no idea if he named his main module `App`, and he's using `app` as this one. In my previous comment I just gave an example for the nested modules.

Comment: That was it. I can't believe I wasted an hour not realizing I didn't return the directive configuration object.